# Solve cos(2x)/sin(x) = c

Tags: trigonometry

This little problem is the simplified version of a physics problem that I am solving for my physics 2300 class at osu. I cannot seem to be able to isolate x to find a solution to this problem

Thank for helping in advance

Comment: write everything in terms of $\sin x$, take $y=\sin x$ and solve a quadratic. Then solve $\sin x = y_1,y_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Write $$\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{1-2\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)}=c$$ and solve a quadratic.
Substituting $$\sin(x)=t$$ we get the solutions
$$\left\{\left\{t\to \frac{1}{4}
   \left(-\sqrt{c^2+8}-c\right)\right\},\left\{t\to
   \frac{1}{4}
   \left(\sqrt{c^2+8}-c\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: My c value turns out to he c= tan(a)/v. So its hard to solve it as a quadratic. Will I have to use the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\cos(2x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=1-2\sin^2x$.

Comment: My C value turns out to be c= tan(a)/v